# how to connect to physical mongo database(i.e. Non-Cloud mongo db server) using AWSlambda function

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda

while connecting physical mongo DB from AWS lambda function getting an error like "MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ". Could you pls guide me how to connect mongo DB using AWS lambda function. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

A little more information about your setup would be useful:

- Does the MongoDB server live within your AWS VPC or On-Premises?
- If it resides in AWS, is your Lambda function also part of that VPC?

  - Is DNS Resolution enabled in the VPC?
  - Did you check that the right Security Groups are attached?
- Is the DNS-Name of your MongoDB publicly resolvable (or privately if the Lambda function sits inside the VPC)? - try `nslookup my-mongo-server.com`

**Not having that information I can hazard a guess:**

You probably want to connect to an On-Premises (i.e. not in AWS) instance of MongoDB which sits in a private Network in some Data Center.

You've been given a DNS-Name like `db.mycompany.internal` and are trying to connect to that. The problem is, that this DNS-Name is not publicly resolvable, i.e. the public DNS system doesn't know about your domain.

Your code is trying to get the IP address of your database server to connect to, but can't do that.